# next.js 13 + AWS Amplify build artifact missing some json files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, next.js13

When building AWS Amplify Next.js 13.2 SSR, deployment artifact is missing some json files. Build seems to work and there are .html and .json files for SSG pages. When I download the artifact those files are missing. Those files are also missing from the deployment.

Build log shows:

```
./.next/standalone/.next/server/pages/blogi.json
./.next/standalone/.next/server/pages/blogi.html
```

Artifact has only this file:

```
/.next/server/pages/blogi.html
```